# Android map v2 set position infoWindow

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow

I update my project from Android google map v1 to map v2.
But I have a serious problem, I have to set the entire infoWindow on the screen without changing the position of the map (Only if the window can't enter in the screen).

I make a custom InfoWindowAdapter, but how can I set the position of infoWindow ?
Or do something to make the infoWindow center on the screen, without moving the map to center the infoWindow.

What I want when we clic on the overlay (without moving map)
[image]

If I don't arrive to solve this probleme, I have to return to map v1 :(

I hope, I arrive to explain my problem.

Anthony

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put something in the center of the screen, try using plain old `View`s on top of the map inside `FrameLayout`.

If you really want to reposition the info window, you may want to learn about [`setInfoWindowAnchor`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#setInfoWindowAnchor%28float,%20float%29), but some calculations will be required to make it work properly.

Comment: It's not what I want. SetInfoWindowAnchor, can just move the bottom center of the infowindow inside the overlay. I add exemple of what I need